# Flutter Textfield's height

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to reduce the "default" height of my `TextField` widget so that it matches my model (the bottom one, the top one is my emulator).

[image]

If wrap my `TextField` with a `Container` to put it a height, the TextField's height won't expand as I wanted as the number of line increases.

So I don't know what to do to reduce the default height.

```dart
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
   maxLines: 5,
   minLines: 1,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Saisir le message",
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: MC_lightGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
         borderSide: BorderSide.none,
         borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
             const Radius.circular(10.0),
         ),
       ),
   ),
),
```

Comment: Just remove the `vertical` content padding.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change anything

Comment: Yes, I forgot you have to use the `dense` set as well, otherwise, it has a minimum height set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```dart
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
   maxLines: 5,
   minLines: 1,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      hintText: "Saisir le message",
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: MC_lightGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Add `isDense:true` in `InputDecoration`.

Comment: Yeah that's it thanks !! the `isDense` property, once put to true, reduces it to the minimum height.